# privacy violation shoulder surfing on fortify

Tags: c#, .net, fortify

Web application in .net .in my application I have a property called password but in fortify on demand it's thrown on the issue "privacy violation shoulder surfing". anyone tell me how to fix this issue :)

```
    private string _PasswordAnswer = "";

    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordAnswer{ 
        get
        { 
                        if(_PasswordAnswer == null) _PasswordAnswer = string.Empty;
                        return this._PasswordAnswer;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != this._PasswordAnswer)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("PasswordAnswer");
                this._PasswordAnswer = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PasswordAnswer");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Maybe add more code, this isn't enough to help you out. This should help you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `DataType` Attribute to your property, like this:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is more code quality improvement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype?view=netframework-4.6.2) rather than security.

I also faced this problem in one of the Fortify projects and I'd call it **false positive**. Even if their similar example in the docs they have it written that the plaintext would need to be logged/exposed (https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.java.privacy_violation#C%23%2FVB.NET%2FASP.NET) rather than just change "DataType" in the object's model